Tesseract doesn't use custom language .traineddata file
I'm trying to teach a new font, Beaufort for LOL, to the OCR.
For this, I followed a tutorial in a video utilizing QT-Box editor: https://youtu.be/N5Y6gZgvryQ
But after completing all of the steps and setting Tesseract to use the new language, the output is always empty.
I managed to complete every step 1:1 (except renaming "arial" to "beaufortforlol", which was also set in the QT-Box editor) and yet, nothing is saved in "output.txt" file after running:
tesseract testlan.beaufortforlol.exp0.png output.txt -l testlan
in cmd, whereas it should contain the text of the inputted image. I also tried to use my python script with pytesseract specifying the new "testlan" language, but again nothing was produced. It's interesting that my "testlan.traineddata" is definitely recognized, because the script doesn't even return any errors - which happens only when I try to set an unrecognizable language.
I made sure that my "testlan.traineddata" is in the corect directory ("C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata", along with eng.traineddata").
Edit: Relevant files (traineddata, .png, python script): https://fileport.io/mUqmJTyr659Z
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
img_file = "OCRdata/no_noise.jpg"
img = Image.open(img_file)
ocr_result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='testlan')
print(ocr_result)


add your code to make your question reproducible

Sharing my testlan.traineddata, image to be read (used for the training) and the python script to launch the OCR: https://fileport.io/mUqmJTyr659Z

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Do not follow internet tutorials - usually, they are outdated (e.g. QT-Box editor was created for tesseract 3.x and the current version is 5.3.4).
BTW OCR training from scratch is difficult, resource-consuming, and requires knowledge.
Use the official training procedure (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesstrain) which allows fine-tuning of existing models.
